# c++ missing some output results

Tags: c++, destructor

I found this code in one c++ test:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 2) : m_i(n) { }

    ~A() { std::cout << m_i; }

protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B
    : public A
{
public:
    B(int n) : m_x(m_i + 1) , m_a(n) { }

public:
    ~B()
    {
        std::cout << m_i;
        --m_i;
    }

private:
    A m_x;
    A m_a;
};

int main()
{
    { B b(5); }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

The answer is: 2531. But as I understood, here just called two destructors:
first for B, which entered 2;
second for A, which entered 1;
 How we got numbers 5 and 3? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you use a debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`B` also has two data members of type `A`, and the destructor for those objects (`m_a` first, `m_x` second, in reverse declaration order) is invoked after the destructor of `B`.

So what is going on here is:

1. When constructing `b`, the constructor of its `A` base sub-object is called first, and that is default-constructed, since the initializer list of `B`'s constructor does not specify any argument for `A`. This means `b.m_i` will be `2`;
2. The constructors of the `m_x` and `m_a` sub-objects of `b` will be invoked, in declaration order, passing the specified arguments. This means `b.m_x.m_i` will be `3` (`b.m_i + 1`), and `b.m_a.m_i` will be `5` (`n`);
3. The body of the constructor of `B` for `b` gets executed (there is nothing to be done here);
4. The destructor of `B` is executed, which will output `2` and decrement `b.m_i` (that will become `1`);
5. The destructor of `m_a` is executed (it appears first in reverse declaration order), and it will print `5`;
6. The destructor of `m_x` is executed, and `3` is printed;
7. The destructor of `b`'s `A` sub-object is executed, and will print `b.m_i`, which is now `1`.

Comment: Thanks.Did not pay attention that their type is A, just kept in mind, that they are int. Sorry for my inadvertence.

Comment: @VitaliK: No problem, I edited the answer to clarify what is going on in detail

Answer (score 0):

When you create you B item, it creates 2 A items, with value 3 and 5.